# Get all variable and constant names declared in a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to get list of all variables and constants defined in packages within given schema using data dictionary.

Couldn't find any information how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do the same as PLSQL developper does when opening a package? Try *enable SQL TRACE* on a session, then open a package and see what happens.

Comment: I need a request that returns list of variables and constants. Something like this:
   1 PACKAGE1            Variable          var1
   2 PACKAGE2     Const          const1
   3 PACKAGE1     Const        const2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PL/Scope can provide this, although it's a compiler option that you need to enable explicitly.

1. Enable PL/Scope

   ```
   alter session set plscope_settings = 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL';
   ```
2. Recompile the schema or selected objects, e.g. (this will recompile all objects for the selected schema:

   ```
   exec dbms_utility.compile_schema('MYSCHEMA',TRUE);
   ```
3. Now you can query for all identifiers in objects owned by the current user:

   ```
   select * from user_identifiers;
   ```